# SwiftUI LazyVGrid: Expanding view causes LazyVGrid animation bug

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation, lazyvgrid

Expanding a SwiftUI View causes the LazyVGrid to remove all the items that will not be seen when the animation is completed. Additionally, when scrolling down the items animate from their original position to their actual position.

Here is the code I wrote to replicate the problem:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var isOpen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Color.green
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            isOpen.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 500)
                    .frame(height: isOpen ? nil : 50, alignment: .top)
                    .clipped()

                
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 75, maximum: 100))]) {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                        Color.black
                            .frame(height: 30)
                            .overlay {
                                Text("index: \(index)")
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the LazyVGrid items to first be removed from the grid when the animation is completed, also the items shouldn't animate to their new position.

Any help is appreciated

Edit:
Here is a link to a Video of the problem: [git link](https://github.com/Joel2307/Video/blob/master/StackOverflowBug729.mov)